# Python tkinter Enter new Page Frame after do something success application crashed

Tags: tkinter

Trying to execute card_pay() method and when it success , enter new Page_6(Frame) ,also I set a button clicked to next page, the button Next_Page() is working ,but the method card_pay failed, it will cause the application crashed.below is my method to change page.

```
self.page_6 = Page_6(self.root)
self.pack_forget()
self.page_6.pack()
```

my code:

```
class Page_5(Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master 
        self.createPage()
    def createPage(self):
        search_card=True
        Page_Image = Image.open('D:/API_nomal/page_image/5.png')
        Page_Image_PIL=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Page_Image)
        Button_Image = Image.open('D:/API_nomal/page_image/confirm.png')
        Button_Image_PIL=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Button_Image)
        label=Label(self,image=Page_Image_PIL)
        label.image=Page_Image_PIL
        button_pay=Button(self,image = Button_Image_PIL,command=lambda: self.Next_Page(),border='0',bg='white', takefocus = 0)
        button_pay.image=Button_Image_PIL
        button_pay.place(x=877, y=895)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        car_pay_thread = Thread(target=self.card_pay)
        car_pay_thread.start()
    def card_pay(self):
        global search_card
        while debug_flag==True:
            try:
                if search_card== True:
                    self.page_6 = Page_6(self.root)
                    self.pack_forget()
                    self.page_6.pack()
            except Exception as e :
                print traceback.format_exc()

    def Next_Page(self):
        self.page_6 = Page_6(self.root)
        self.pack_forget()
        self.page_6.pack()

class Page_6(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        self.createPage()

    def createPage(self):
        Page_Image = Image.open('D:/API_nomal/page_image/6.png')
        Page_Image_PIL=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Page_Image)
        label=Label(self,image=Page_Image_PIL)
        label.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e=Page_Image_PIL:self.Next_Page())
        label.pack()

    def Next_Page(self):
        self.inital_page = Initial_Page(self.root)
        self.pack_forget()
```

Comment: first of I hope you understand that you can make one class for all pages? You most likely do not need to create a new class for every page if they are similar. classes can be used as templates

Comment: once `debug_flag` is `True`, there is nothing in your loop to ever change it to `False`, thus creating an infinite loop.